# Preventing truncation of trees

Tags: trees, version-12.3

In regards to the new tree functionality in Mathematica 12.3, apparently the display is collapsed/summarized when an element has more than 10 sub-elements, so what I was expecting to be displayed as 11 is replaced by a <<1>>:

```
RulesTree[1 -> Range[11]]
```

[image: tree]

is there an way of preventing this to display the full tree?

**UPDATE**: I have found that there is a symbol Trees`$VisualizationMaxChildren which is protected. It can be unprotected and changed to avoid the truncation. I'll leave the question open as this is kind of a hack, but it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a protected, internal parameter you can tweak:

```
Unprotect[Trees`$VisualizationMaxChildren];
Trees`$VisualizationMaxChildren = 12;
Protect[Trees`$VisualizationMaxChildren];
RulesTree[1 -> Range[12]]
Unprotect[Trees`$VisualizationMaxChildren];
Trees`$VisualizationMaxChildren = 10;
Protect[Trees`$VisualizationMaxChildren];
```

[image]

The value is used at the time `MakeBoxes[]` is called, so if you change the value of `$VisualizationMaxChildren` back to `10` within a code before the tree is returned and converted to boxes, it won't work.

Does not work:

```
Block[{Trees`$VisualizationMaxChildren = 12},
 RulesTree[1 -> Range[12]]
 ]
```

Works:

```
Block[{Trees`$VisualizationMaxChildren = 12},
 With[{expr = RulesTree[1 -> Range[12]]}, 
  MakeBoxes[expr, StandardForm] // RawBoxes]
 ]
```

Comment: Oh, well, I was lazy. I answered the Q before reading it completely.... :)

Comment: Thanks, you added much more detail to my update in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Trees are still being considered as Experimental in 12.3, and there are no visualization options yet ([source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8XOaF6yq9R4&t=1427s)).

I think you will have to rely on `TreePlot`:

```
TreePlot[Flatten@Table[{1 -> i}, {i, 2, 12}], VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image: TreePlot]